# Scapy: no reply on raw ICMP packet

Tags: python, packet, scapy

I've constructed a packet with `scapy`:

```
a=IP(dst='192.168.0.1',proto=1)/'\x08\x00\xf7\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

I run:

```
send(a)
```

Wireshark shows me that there is a ping request and ping response from 192.168.0.1
No warnings, all fields are correct

But when I try:

```
b=sr1(a)
```

Then Scapy can't get an answer (Wireshark shows me again that there is request and reply)

What can I do with it?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `scapy` doesn't know how to recognize the response because you are honestly building an ICMP packet the hard way.  If you build it with `ICMP()`, it will work...

```
>>> from scapy.all import ICMP, IP, sr1
>>> aa = IP(dst='192.168.0.1')/ICMP()
>>> sr1(aa)
Begin emission:
Finished to send 1 packets.
*
Received 1 packets, got 1 answers, remaining 0 packets
<IP  version=4L ihl=5L tos=0x0 len=28 id=21747 flags= frag=0L ttl=60 proto=icmp 
chksum=0x1a77 src=192.168.0.1 dst=4.121.2.25 options=[] |<ICMP  type=echo-reply 
code=0 chksum=0x0 id=0x0 seq=0x0 |<Padding  
load='\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00' |>>>
>>>
```

Comment: aa = IP(dst='192.168.0.1')/ICMP()
sr1(aa)
when i call sr1(aa) i can't receive any reply packet.

Comment: Hello @Rick stack overflow comments are not the right way to get the question answered.  Please consider formally asking a stack overflow question.