# ICMP destination unreachable error scapy

Tags: python, python-2.7, packet, scapy, traffic

I was testing ICMP response:
when I send a UDP segment/packet to a port using Scapy, It gets send to the destination saying malformed packet(Unknown Operation) and destination replies with the proper ICMP port unreachable message. 
Could anyone shed some light on this or am I doing a stupid mistake here?
    This is my script for doing so;

```
# Generate packet
pkts3 = IP(dst="10.0.0.2")/UDP()/Raw(RandString(size=120))
#print pkts
pkts3[UDP].flags = "S"

pktList3 = []
for pktNum3 in range(0,5):
    pktList3.extend(pkts3)
    pktList3[pktNum3][UDP].dport = 520 # Pkt has Ran PortNo.
    print pktList3[pktNum3].summary()
    #print len(pktList[pktNum])
    #wrpcap('tcp-packets.pcap',pktList[pktNum])

# Send the list of packets send(pktList)
start_time3=time.time()
send(pktList3)
totalTime = time.time()-start_time3
totalBytes=(5*120)/totalTime
#print pktList3[0].show()
print pktList3[0].show2()
print totalBytes,"Seconds"
```

Comment: What is the output when you print?

Comment: It generate the Packets but doesn't send properly. The output I get is: [link] https://www.dropbox.com/s/z6y790vfpx9yv8z/udpPacket.jpg

Comment: You have print statements in your code, I wanted to see that output, not Wireshark.

Comment: Output: https://www.dropbox.com/s/pl0d37tlbvgkysy/udp.png

Answer (score 0):

You may do the following (Scapy 2.2.0)

1) Use ICMP packets from Scapy (seems that your packets aren't correct)

```
from scapy.layers import inet, inet6
icmpPacket = inet.ICMP()
```

Then concatenate as usual with operator `/`. ICMP runs over IPv4.

2) In addition to the previous point you need to modify `Ethernet` part in packets with Scapy. You may need correct MAC addresses of your sender and receiver to get proper replies.

Examples:

- http://thepacketgeek.com/scapy-p-06-sending-and-receiving-with-scapy/
- [Scapy: no reply on raw ICMP packet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389000/scapy-no-reply-on-raw-icmp-packet?rq=1)
- http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html

Comment: The Issue is the emulator mininet which I am using doesn't allow UDP packets but it is working fine for TCP. How would I be able to allow UDP packets to flow in the emulator