# Scapy Windows sr1() not being answered

Tags: python-2.6, scapy

I'm using the Scapy library for Python 2.6 on Windows 7 in order to see if I can spoof my IP address (for non-malicious purposes, I'm curious how it works).

When I use the `sr1()` function, it sends the packet, but it gets nothing in return. I have to interrupt it manually using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in order for it to stop receiving packets that are not an answer.

[image: Here's a screenshot]

I've tried to use both [Python-Scapy or the like-How can I create an HTTP GET request at the packet level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750793/python-scapy-or-the-like-how-can-i-create-an-http-get-request-at-the-packet-leve) and [Scapy: no reply on raw ICMP packet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389000/scapy-no-reply-on-raw-icmp-packet), with no luck.

I have tried tracking it in Wireshark, but nothing showed up.

I know Scapy is not made for Windows, so that could be the issue. If so, I can get a Linux environment instead.

NOTE: Note that I am running this through the console version of Scapy, but I found the exact same results running it through Python scripts.

Answer (score 0):

> IP(dst="www.google.com")/TCP(dport=80,flags="S")

This TCP packet's sport will automatically set to be 20 (www-data) in Scapy.

And what is worse, www.google.com does not reply from the sport=20 (www-data)

try

> IP(dst="www.google.com")/TCP(sport=65000,dport=80,flags="S")